# How to Insert records into a table in Unity using SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add a record to my table using string variables for VarChar columns. I want to insert the values I give it under the next incremented ID. However, I keep getting the SQL error that "no such column exists" when I try and run the code. There is no elaboration on where the error occurs, so I'm sorta stuck. So how can I insert records into a table?

Here's my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using System.Data;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class AddQuery : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text cipher;
    public Text initialMessage;
    public Text encryptedMessage;

    private string _constr = "URI=file:previousMessages.db";
    private IDbConnection _dbc;
    private IDbCommand _dbcm;
    private IDataReader _dbr;


public void AddSQL() {
    string _cipher = cipher.text;
    string _initialMessage = initialMessage.text;
    string _encryptedMessage = encryptedMessage.text;

    _dbc = new SqliteConnection(_constr);
    _dbc.Open();

    _dbcm = _dbc.CreateCommand();
    _dbcm.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS previousMessages (ID    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , Cipher   VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL, InitialMessage  VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL,EncryptedMessage TEXT NOT NULL)";
    _dbr = _dbcm.ExecuteReader();
    _dbr.Close();

    _dbcm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO previousMessages ( Cipher, InitialMessage, EncryptedMessage) VALUES ( "+_cipher+", "+_initialMessage+", "+_encryptedMessage+")";
    _dbr = _dbcm.ExecuteReader();
    _dbr.Close();

    _dbcm.CommandText = "SELECT FROM previousMessages (Cipher, InitialMessage, EncryptedMessage) VALUES ( " + _cipher + ", " + _initialMessage + ", " + _encryptedMessage + ")";
    _dbr = _dbcm.ExecuteReader();

    while (_dbr.Read())
    {
        Debug.Log("Cipher: " + _dbr["Cipher"] + "\t Initial: " + _dbr["InitialMessage"]);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow OOP you're life will be simpler. I mean you'd rather let a method do only one thing; or if it HAS TO do many things than make it a list of calls to other methods which do only 1 thing each. That being said your `AddSQL()` breaks down to:

```
public void AddSQL() {
    string _cipher = cipher.text;
    string _initialMessage = initialMessage.text;
    string _encryptedMessage = encryptedMessage.text;

    OpenConnection();
    ExecuteCreateCommand();
    InsertCommand(_cipher, _initialMessage, _encryptedMessage);
    ReadStuff(_cipher, _initialMessage, _encryptedMessage);
    DebugRead();

}

void OpenConnection(){
    _dbc = new SqliteConnection(_constr);
    _dbc.Open();
}

void ExecuteCreateCommand(){
    _dbcm = _dbc.CreateCommand();
    _dbcm.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS previousMessages (ID    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , Cipher   VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL, InitialMessage  VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL,EncryptedMessage TEXT NOT NULL)";
    _dbr = _dbcm.ExecuteReader();
    _dbr.Close();
}

void InsertCommand(string _cipher, string _initialMessage, string _encryptedMessage){
    _dbcm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO previousMessages ( Cipher, InitialMessage, EncryptedMessage) VALUES ( "+_cipher+", "+_initialMessage+", "+_encryptedMessage+")";
    _dbr = _dbcm.ExecuteReader();
    _dbr.Close();
}

void ReadStuff(string _cipher, string _initialMessage, string _encryptedMessage){
    _dbcm.CommandText = "SELECT FROM previousMessages (Cipher, InitialMessage, EncryptedMessage) VALUES ( " + _cipher + ", " + _initialMessage + ", " + _encryptedMessage + ")";
    _dbr = _dbcm.ExecuteReader();
}

void DebugRead(){
    while (_dbr.Read())
    {
        Debug.Log("Cipher: " + _dbr["Cipher"] + "\t Initial: " + _dbr["InitialMessage"]);
    }
}
```

Now in `AddSQL()` comment all the method calls and uncomment one by one to see which query throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I can be a bit messy at times with my coding. I still keep getting the error that apparently the string "Ceaser" cannot go into my table as "no such column exists". Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: The point was to let you know which line gives you an error. But well, I assume in `ExecuteCreateCommand()` and in `InsertCommand()` you need to use `_dbcm.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `_dbcm.ExecuteReader()`. Not sure though. [ExecuteNonQuery docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) say you can use this for *creating database objects such as tables*